# Location for User Feedback on eOS 6

Tags: kernel

I'm testing one of the early access/preview eOS 6 downloads for the first time -- wondering if there is a specific venue to provide feedback from a general user perspective and to ask specific questions?

Thanks!

Comment: Specific questions should probably go here, on this site. Also, why is this flagged with 'kernel'? Though you can surely ask questions in chat, if needed. Chat is here: https://community-slack.elementary.io/

Comment: Ok.  Orients me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

I felt that this needed a canonical answer, so I decided to go get the information and share it.

First, let me share an image:

[image]

As you can see, the GitHub link is [here](http://github.com/elementary). You can report or comment there, though you'll need an account to do so.

If it's a problem, like a bug, then you can file it this way:

Click on Settings → About → Report a Problem and fill in the information.

Further, if you'd like, you can also visit their Slack chat [here](https://community-slack.elementary.io/).